# Make a copy of a File with PHP or JavaScript

Tags: php

How can I make a copy of a file on my server from a site either in PHP or JavaScript?

I tried the following:

```
<?php
$file = 'example.txt';
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
?>
```

But I keep getting the "failed to copy" message

I created a copy.php file in my var/www/html folder (Using Apache in Ubuntu)  and I ran the copy.php file in my browser http://localhost/copy.php

My example.txt is sitting right in the same folder that copy.php

Thanks

Comment: If you viewed the error log (ubuntu defaults to `/var/log/apache2/error.log`) you would likely see more detail about what is failing. This usually is an issue with file permissions. The `apache` user must have write permissions on the folder you are copying to and if the `example.txt.bak` file exists, the `apache` user would also need permissions to write to that file.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn  I look at the error.log document and it was a permission issue. I changed permissions as suggested to 0700 and now when I run the php file I get the following error in the browser:  **You don't have permission to access /copy.php on this server.**  and I get the following in the error.log:  `[Wed Apr 06 16:01:54.575943 2016] [core:error] [pid 2160] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:46744] AH00035: access to /SweatMeal/NEW/copy.php denied (filesystem path '/var/www/html/copy.php') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path`  THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You need to set destination folder permissions to 646. Use your domain cpanel or equivalent to do that

Comment: That's a really bad and _wrong_ advice. 0646 means that _everybody_ can write to that directory, but you can't really change into that directory. What you ideally want is 0700 and ensure that the directory is owned by the user that the web server is run as, although 0755 is a more common scenario.

Comment: @AleksG  I ran the command: sudo chmod 0700 folder and now I don't have access to any of the files. I get the following error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access Folder on this server

Comment: @MartinD Have you changed the ownership of the Folder to the user, under which the web server is running?  That's the reason for both this issue and your original question.

Comment: run sudo again and set permissions to 646, any DIRECTLY LOGGED USER can change in that folder, but web users are not logged users, php works with anonymous user. Web users only could copy to that folder through php

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu you would need to set your folder permissions so navigate to your project directory using cd in the command prompt 'cd /var/www/html/myproject'

var/www/html/myproject

Lets say the folder your want to copy to is located at

var/www/html/myproject/copied_files

now run the command 'sudo chown -R <your username on ubuntu>:www-data <folder name>

It should look like this
Lets say my user name is  prince

prince@computer: var/www/html/myproject $ sudo chown -R prince:www-data copied_files

Essentially your giving the group "www-data" which is your server permission to write files to that directory while you still have ownership to it. The '-R' says that all subfolders should be writable by 'www-data' (your server) so you don't have to manually make it writeable and the 'copied_files' is the name of directory for your server to write too :)